# Difference between string encoded through PHP and SHELL code with OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl, cryptography

Those 2 codes are working separately but do not give the same result even if they rely on the same library

They both :

- read the content of of file named plaintext.txt
- creates a 32-byte hash from the provided key
- creates a 16-byte hash from the provided Initialization vector
- encrypt the content using  AES-256-CBC
- write the encrypted content encoded in base64 into a file named ciphertext.base64

PHP

```php
<?php

$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$secret_iv = 'YYYYYYYYY';

// hashes
$key = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_key), 0, 32);
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

$string = file_get_contents('plaintext.txt');

$output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
//By default the output is already in base64
file_put_contents('ciphertext.base64', $output);
?>
```

BASH

```bash
key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
secret_iv='YYYYYYYYY'

keyhash=$(echo -n $key | sha256sum | cut -c 1-32)
ivhash=$(echo -n $secret_iv | sha256sum | cut -c 1-16)

openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -K "$keyhash" -iv "$ivhash" -in plaintext.txt -out ciphertext.base64 -base64
```

I really don't understand why the results are different. Moreover in php the IV must have a length of 16 while the shells complains it should be 32

Any tip ?

In bash, I've noticed 32 0 are added to key (64 characters) and 16 0 to IV (32 characters) which is probably the result of the warning "hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length"

Comment: You are confusing bytes with their hex encoding. One byte is 8 bits, but all 256 possible values are possible. Command-line programs for crypto like `sha256sum` and `openssl` also must be able to input and output arbitrary bytes, but for humans it much easier to hex-encode a byte using two characters from the set [0-9A-F]. Thus 16 bytes may require 32 characters. The man pages for these commands will explain the formats expected on input/output precisely, e.g. for [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-enc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the key and IV in PHP/OpenSSL must be passed as *raw* values (i.e. binary strings) to [`openssl_encrypt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php), they must be specified *hex encoded* in the OpenSSL statement (s. [*openssl-enc*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html), `-K`. `-iv` options).
Both are not done correctly in the code (possibly because, as already suspected in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77684893/difference-between-string-encoded-through-php-and-shell-code-with-openssl/77685704#comment136957328_77684893), binary and hex encoded data are confused):

- In the PHP code, for the key and IV not the raw hash values are used, but the hex encoded hash values. The *direct* use of hex encoded hash values is a vulnerability, as the value range for each byte is reduced from 256 to 16 bytes. This should therefore be fixed. To do this, the third parameter of the [`hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function must be set to `true`:

  ```php
  $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key, true);
  $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv, true), 0, 16);
  ```
- In the bash script, the hex encoded hash values are truncated. To fix this, use the correct lengths (64 hex digits or 32 bytes for the key and 32 hex digits or 16 bytes for the IV):

  ```bash
  keyhash=$(echo -n $key | sha256sum)                      
  ivhash=$(echo -n $secret_iv | sha256sum | cut -c 1-32)
  ```

---

If the PHP code cannot/should not be changed despite the mentioned disadvantage and the hex encoded values are to be used directly as key and IV, an additional hex encoding is required in the batch script:

```bash
keyhashstr=$(echo -n $key | sha256sum | cut -c 1-32)               
keyhash=$(printf '%s' $keyhashstr | hexdump -ve '/1 "%02X"')
ivhashstr=$(echo -n $secret_iv | sha256sum | cut -c 1-16)               
ivhash=$(printf '%s' $ivhashstr | hexdump -ve '/1 "%02X"')
```

(or with `xxd` instead of `hexdump`).

---

Security: Regarding the term `secret_iv`: The IV is not a secret and therefore does not need to be kept secret. However, it is a vulnerability if a *static* IV is used, as this results in a reuse of key/IV pairs if the same key is used. To prevent this, a common approach is to generate a random IV for each encryption. The IV is passed together with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, usually concatenated.
When using a passphrase, another vulnerability is to use a fast digest for key derivation. More secure is a key derivation function such as PBKDF2 in conjunction with a random (also not secret) salt.